# Is the History Stack activity experiencing a major downward trend?

Tags: discussion

When looking at the year in moderation post, I did a little digging, and checked the question counts over the last 10 years using the search ***is:question created:*year****. We get the following numbers:

| Year | Questions Asked | Closed:true |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 755 | 86 |
| 2021 | 962 | 132 |
| 2020 | 1342 | 216 |
| 2019 | 1402 | 161 |
| 2018 | 1720 | 144 |
| 2017 | 1812 | 230 |
| 2016 | 1420 | 238 |
| 2015 | 1250 | 225 |
| 2014 | 1103 | 193 |
| 2013 | 1127 | 127 |
| 2012 | 830 | 102 |
| 2011 | 364 | 35 |

(Note these numbers do reflect both open and closed questions from each year, but do not (can not) include questions which have been deleted.)

*Update:*
Added a new column which represents a portion of the questions asked, but are closed in the system (closed:true). This still doesn't represent questions which have been deleted.

A graph of the above data looks like this:[image]

It appears there was a steady increase in questions asked up until 2017 and we have been losing activity ever since. It also seems our closure rate has remained fairly consistent.

---

Grabbing a look at the sites analytics as suggested by @LаngLаngС seems on the surface to confirm this:
[image]

Note the highest post count corresponds with the same year mentioned in the table above.

One question we need to consider: is is this trend just ours, or is it overall to the SE community in general?

If it is just *our* issue, what do we need to do to fix it?

(My son, half in jest, mentioned that it could be a diminishing returns type issue-we have so many answers posted already that new questions are mostly duplicates or are unnecessary).

Comment: Depending on whether 'it's allowed', sth like visuals from \https://history.[meta].stackexchange.com/site-analytics might be included?

Comment: Does https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/site-analytics work? (I edited the eariler link, to include meta & main)

Comment: That one works.

Comment: I'm curious how this compares to other graduated non-technical sites. I do some po-man's analytics every now and then, and it seems like most of them are down more than we are.

Comment: That's part of why I deleted the other response in the first place. Raw numbers without context have limited usefulness.

Comment: Well, it looks like it requires 25k rep on a site to look at its site-analytics, and the only other one I have that much on is a technical site (close on English tho), so I can't compare that way.

Comment: Perhaps one of our visiting mods from other sites might have more info access for their sites? The search engine [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49424/introducing-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-aka-sede) might have more capabilities, but someone needs to have access to script it as well?

Comment: Apart from the things mentioned, perhaps needed for more insight: how many unregistered users posting decide to register? How many users start earning  reps from non-HNQs, 2-or-more posts? How did numbers like these develop over the years? [Are driving factors: Q-closures, 'perceived as nasty' comments, sub-par As, no-As, (what else)?] One factor probably being at work here is a variation of your son's suspicion: the higher the rep of a user, the lower the tendency of that very user to ask Qs, so that might be a harvest effect while SE approaches a ceiling? But SEDE needs insight from staff.

Comment: @justCal Do the statistics include closed questions? We had a lot more low quality questions back then.

Comment: @axsvl77 The numbers my table reference *do* include *some* closed questions, but from what I have been able to deduce *don't* include *deleted* questions. The basic search abilities don't seem to give us the ability to access or quantify deleted questions, at least at a non-moderator/or staff level.

Comment: It's impossible to ask questions these days without it being sealioned to death. And I've been on the site for 8 years - imagine how daunting it is for a new user.

Comment: Hmm. New term for me, [sealioned](https://medium.com/digital-diplomacy/welcome-to-advanced-trolling-sealioning-9bfb78fb1f51#:~:text=The%20term%20sealioning%20was%20derived,a%20million%20bad%2Dfaith%20questions.&text=It%20is%20not%20for%20the%20faint%20of%20heart.&text=At%20its%20core%2C%20however%2C%20those,they're%20annoying%20as%20hell.) *Death by a million bad-faith questions.*.

Comment: To be clear, I don't think most of the questions in comments are bad-faith. Individually they're ok. But e.g. being expected to define everything to death, and not permitting any room for querent and repondent to use common sense in understanding such words as 'ruler', 'country', 'farmer', 'slave', 'soldier' and other very common words is exhausting for everybody. Words can only be defined with other words, after all - at some point I have to presume you and I have a sufficiently similar understanding of words like 'food'.

Comment: The last quarter of 2019 was when SE blew up over Monica, Code of Conduct, whatnot. Statistically I don't know that 2018 and 2017 are particularly different from each other. The odd one to me is the drop in 2021 compared with 2019-2020. Fewer college students really diving into history because of Covid?

Comment: @JonCuster - I think momentum is a thing, since the issue is probably going to be related to relative # of new users vs the constant trickle of existing users who wander off.  So a constant trend in the same direction since the social start of the Pandemic (Earlyish 2020) doesn't seem to require much explanation.

Comment: There's also the issue that actually (inadvertantly) kicked off the "M" situation: SE was auto-tweeting out some HNQs, and there was no human interaction with the HNQ list, which meant a lot of clickbaity stuff was making it onto the HNQ and getting promoted on social media. That meant pushing a lot of problematic stuff with SE's name on it. They got a bad name on social media for doing that, and did a lot of remediation that had the effect of drastically toning down the clickbaity stuff. But ... well .. those shady websites do clickbait for a reason. It does drive traffic.

Comment: What about the voting system, are enough people voting? Can we see the same trend in the amount of questions in the amount of votes? It would be interesting to see if they're both declining and which is leading which.

Comment: @Mast AFAIU , that kind of granularity in data isn't available to 'us'? That's why I 'd like to call in _much_ detailed analysis from staff-level access to data. ('They' could even do  focus group analysis, surveys etc—but raw data analysis, if done right, might already help a lot.) We either need much more help from our benevolent dictators, or access to rawer data ourselves? We see the shadows on the wall of that cave, now they seem clear … but what are they really, and what can we conclude?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is experiencing a downward trend, from all angles available to me:

- personal impression of ad-hoc/heuristic mental 'stats'
- 'official statistics' as presented by site-analytics

Apart from the things mentioned, perhaps needed for more insight:

- How many unregistered users posting decide to register?
- How many users start earning reps from non-HNQs, 2-or-more posts?
- How did numbers like these develop over the years?
- How many users beomce active for a while, but then seem to leave/become inactive again, just by pure visits to the site?

What would certainly be interesting to know:

Are driving perhaps factors:

- 'mere' question-closures (plus subsequent 'staying closed'),
- 'perceived as nasty' comments or downvotes,
- sub-par answers, unanswered questions, (what else)?

One factor probably being at work here is a variation of your son's suspicion: the higher the rep of a user, the lower the tendency of that very user to ask questions.
So that might be a harvest effect while SE itself and overall approaches a slow-down or even ceiling in new user recruitment? Certainly this downward trend occurs to me on some other sites on which I have analytics privileges.

But this and things like SEDE queries need more insight from staff. Or some clever queries by more SEDE experienced users. If anyone with the skills and motivation for more insight comes along and reads this: please share your results!

One aspect apparently lacking from the statistics in this question is 'how many questions were deleted?'. That would be quite a distortion of post mortem analysis. If we received much more posts but also got even more so 'much better' at deleting questions, then the observed trend might not be an indicator of 'reduced activity' at all but a rather different situation: simply 'us' sieving out more posts.

But It seems that this is covered by current site-analytics. But one aspect for this, *albeit not broken down between questions and answers,* is to be gleaned from "20xx a year in moderation posts", which sadly only started appearing in 2018:

| Posts Deleted in | by Moderators | by Community | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 582 | 855 | 1437 |
| 2019 | 409 | 1143 | 1552 |
| 2020 | 483 | 1289 | 1772 |
| 2021 | 238 | 857 | 1095 |

So, while we see a steady increase in post deletions prior to 2021 (with a perhaps seen as welcome trend of community taking a bigger share from 'moderator-duties'), the drastic slump in 2021 seems to rule out ''better' at deletion' as a big explainer for this trend.

At this point I can only repeat that 'hidden' statistics, available to staff, need to be analysed as well.

One step into this direction might be to suggest or even demand a more fine-grained statistic section from "20xx a year in moderation"? Like: also adding a section on general statistics and site activity?

Ready-made SEDE-queries that seem relevant on this would be

- [Total Questions and Answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/history/query/6134/total-questions-and-answers-per-month-for-the-last-12)

[image]

For comparison, other sites and their development look like this:

— MedicalSciences (still 'Health' on SEDE) seems to contradict most theories about 'pandemic effects, early 2020'…

[image]

— Politics

[image]

— Skeptics

[image]

— History of Science and Mathematics, noteworthy in its difference

[image]

Stable sites seem those like WorldBuilding, still in upward trend are for example Islam and Christianty…

- [Bounties and Questions by Month](https://data.stackexchange.com/history/query/7672/bounties-and-questions-by-month)

[image]

Those queries can be compared with other SE sites.

For [Stackoverflow the bounties graph looks like this:](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7672/bounties-and-questions-by-month#graph)

[image]

[For 2022, we see in terms of participation in terms of Meta *voting*
for the entire year so far (–September) *only five users* casting 80 votes altogether so far!](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=year)

Comment: Being unsure about the reliability of "The Historian"-bot in [chat]: would it be useful to scrape that for dates of questions posted? At least my impression is that this would show _all_ questions posted, including deleted ones, that then could be plotted against dates?

Comment: HSM might be due to a smaller sample size.